# Creating minesweep in C++ using vector arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, matrix, minesweeper

So basically im trying to create the computer game minesweeper for uni. I got it working with arrays, but now i have found out i have to use vectors instead which i am completely helpless with. If any one could help me it would be great. Basically i want to use vectors to create a matrix that will get bigger after each round of the game is played. There will be three rounds, the first one starting with a 9x9 matrix, then 12x12 then 24x24. One of the arrays will be made up completely of X's and the second will have randomly generated mines hidden within it, along with any neseccary numbers that are touching the mines. Any help at all would be much appreciated and if there were little pointers in any code that is sent to help me understand it would be fantastic :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific question??

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a vector of vectors, e.g.`vector<vector<int>>`? I'm not sure if this has performance issues. But it's just a simple game, so who cares?

Comment: "But it's just a simple game, so who cares?" The biggest thing about this is a human can only input at a certain rate. Any inefficiency created by using vector<vector<int>> will not make a difference since it will be so much smaller (100s of nanoseconds?) than what a human can input or even notice.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant. No very-optimized-code is needed in such a game.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using vectors.

```
vector<vector<char> > map ( size, vector<char> ( size ) );
```

That creates a 2d vector of char's of size x size.
How you use it exactly depends on the structure of your game's code.